# Using the ns() function from the splines package inside glm()

Tags: r, model, glm, spline

I'm trying to use the `ns()` function from the **splines** package with a poisson GLM I am using to test for significance of particulate matter concentration (`pm.lag0`) on health outcomes (`Freq`):

```
   > gfit4 = glm(Freq ~ pm.lag0 + ns(date, df=2), family = poisson(), 
                 data = dt,  offset = log(pop))
```

I get these errors back:

```
Error in splineDesign(knots, x, ord, derivs, outer.ok = outer.ok) : 
  must have at least 'ord' knots
In addition: Warning message:
In sort(as.numeric(knots)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is that not a valid use of `ns()`? Can someone help me decode this error message? The splines documentation that R provides doesn't seem to match this error (`?ns`).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before you ask many more questions, may I suggest that you spend a few minutes reading a particular section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @joran- sure i will- i definitely don't want to violate the StackOverflow policies. Is there something specific you were pointing out that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What Ben said, plus the fact that it's really helpful (but by no means required) if folks accept the answer that solved their problem.

Comment: Oh, and you weren't violating anything, it was just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: @mEvans The point about a reproducible example is that it allows someone else (like me) to,um, reproduce your problem.  Then I can read the source code, read the help page etc. If you had posted a reproducible example, I may have investigated.  But since you haven't, I am not inclined to spend the time to build my own example  and trace the problem. So I'm ignoring the question and moving on. The point is that you may be lucky and somebody happens to know the answer. Or you can provide more information and possibly get someone interested enough to help you.

Comment: @mEvans please don't presume to know when it is or is not helpful to have a reproducible example. I have hazarded a guess based on my existing knowledge of the functions involved. Others would have been willing to trace the execution of the example to identify the error even if the didn't know what the error might be. Without the reproducible example, as Andrie points illustrates, you will lose the input from that large section of the community, thus restricting yourself to a much smaller subset who have (or, like me think they might have) the required domain-specific knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see a reason why, in principle, it is not possible to use `ns()` in `glm()`. To see why, study what `ns()` does in a formula. From `?ns`

```
> model.frame(weight ~ ns(height, df = 5), data = women)
   weight ns(height, df = 5).1 ns(height, df = 5).2 ns(height, df = 5).3 ns(height, df = 5).4 ns(height, df = 5).5
1     115         0.000000e+00         0.000000e+00         0.000000e+00         0.000000e+00         0.000000e+00
2     117         7.592323e-03         0.000000e+00        -8.670223e-02         2.601067e-01        -1.734045e-01
3     120         6.073858e-02         0.000000e+00        -1.503044e-01         4.509132e-01        -3.006088e-01
4     123         2.047498e-01         6.073858e-05        -1.677834e-01         5.033503e-01        -3.355669e-01
5     126         4.334305e-01         1.311953e-02        -1.324404e-01         3.973211e-01        -2.648807e-01
6     129         6.256681e-01         8.084305e-02        -7.399720e-02         2.219916e-01        -1.479944e-01
7     132         6.477162e-01         2.468416e-01        -2.616007e-02         7.993794e-02        -5.329196e-02
8     135         4.791667e-01         4.791667e-01         1.406302e-02         2.031093e-02        -1.354062e-02
9     139         2.468416e-01         6.477162e-01         9.733619e-02         2.286023e-02        -1.524015e-02
10    142         8.084305e-02         6.256681e-01         2.707683e-01         6.324188e-02        -4.052131e-02
11    146         1.311953e-02         4.334305e-01         4.805984e-01         1.252603e-01        -5.240872e-02
12    150         6.073858e-05         2.047498e-01         5.954160e-01         1.989926e-01         7.809246e-04
13    154         0.000000e+00         6.073858e-02         5.009718e-01         2.755102e-01         1.627794e-01
14    159         0.000000e+00         7.592323e-03         2.246113e-01         3.520408e-01         4.157556e-01
15    164         0.000000e+00         0.000000e+00        -1.428571e-01         4.285714e-01         7.142857e-01
```

Which shows that it provides the B-spline basis for the natural spline of the `height` variable. Nothing special here.

Hence I suspect your `date` variable is not numeric or not something that R could work with by coercing it to be numeric without introducing `NA` - see the warning message. Without a reproducible example and information on your data it is impossible to tell however!

In addition, you might want to look at the `gam()` function in package **mgcv** which as a *Recommended* package is distributed with R. It is designed to fit semi-parametric models in the manner you describe and can include parametric terms as well as smooths/splines of other terms. The package is fairly comprehensive and can fit a large number of types of spline. See it's manual.

Answer (score 1):

Read the help page for the ns function `?ns`, under the section on the `df` argument it includes:

```
One can supply ‘df’ rather than knots;
          ‘ns()’ then chooses ‘df - 1 - intercept’ knots at suitably
          chosen quantiles of ‘x’
```

And since you specified 2 degrees of freedom and did not supress the default intercept that means that you asked it to fit a spline with 0 knots, which it does not know how to do.  Try specifying a larger number for the `df` and it should work for you.